# Dynamic LINQ GroupBy question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using Dyanmic LINQ from the VS2010 code samples as I am trying to create a LINQ groupby expression. 
I want to allow the user the possibility to select at runtime the properties to group on/by as well as the period of grouping (year, quarter, month). Because of this, I decided to go for Dynamic LINQ.

Here's a sample of my data:

ID| Income |   OrDate   | 
1  | 900000   | 1-1-2000 |
2  | 180000       | 1-9-2000 |
3  | 300000      | 3-2-2002 |
4  | 100000     | 2-7-2003 |

and the expression I build looks like:

```
dataSource.GroupBy("new (OrDate.Year as Year, OrDate as Month)", "Income").Select("new (Key.Year, Key.Month, Sum(Value) as Income)");
```

This works well ONLY I know the exact type of the list; for example: `List<Product>` or `List<Order>`. My problem is that the dataSource type at compile time is a `List<object>`. Because of this, whenever I fill the list with Orders or Products, I get an exception:

```
No generic method 'GroupBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.
```

Can anyone tell me how can this be avoided and still keep the source list as a `List<object>`?

Comment: Does this even compile if `dataSource` is a `List<T>`? The `GroupBy` method in Dynamic LINQ is an extension method of `IQueryable`, not of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: My bad, you're right it's a IQueryable.

Comment: Is it a non-generic `IQueryable` or an `IQueryable<object>`? I've tried to reproduce the error, but I only get errors like "OrDate is not a member of type Object", but not your error message. Can you clarify a bit more what `dataSource` exactly is and where it comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
For group by in LinQ

var x = t.GroupBy(gp => gp.Name).OrderBy(group => group.Key).Select(group => Tuple.Create(group.Key, group.Count()));
```

Please find

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WPqzhJ